# Map order to non-sequential input-output values

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I am trying to parse an XML file in order to determine an order of events.  Each element I am trying to extract has an ID.  These IDs are unique to a specific element.  Each element contains an input ID and an output ID.  Some elements can have multiple output IDs.  An example of the relationship appears below:

| InputToolID | OutputToolID | Step |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 48 | 3 |

An example of the XML:

```
    <Connection>
      <Origin ToolID="1" Connection="Output" />
      <Destination ToolID="3" Connection="Input" />
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
      <Origin ToolID="2" Connection="Output" />
      <Destination ToolID="1" Connection="Input" />
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
      <Origin ToolID="3" Connection="Unique" />
      <Destination ToolID="5" Connection="Input" />
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
      <Origin ToolID="3" Connection="Duplicates" />
      <Destination ToolID="6" Connection="Input" />
    </Connection>
    <Connection>
      <Origin ToolID="3" Connection="Unique" />
      <Destination ToolID="48" Connection="Input" />
    </Connection>
```

I have used other parts of the XML to determine that ToolID 2 is my starting point and ToolID 48 is the end of this route.

Is it possible using python to programmatically indicate the starting ToolID and determine the path necessary to reach the ending ToolID?

Comment: yes, it should be possible - but this need to write all code from scratch. Maybe you should first get all data as normal list with rows or as dataframe and check which value in `InputToolID` doesn't exits in `OutputToolID` - you could use `set()` for this. `set(one_list) - set(other_list)`. And if you create dictionary with values from `InputToolID` as keys (and values from `OutputToolID`) then you could simply walk dictionary and get path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have values as lists or DataFrame then you could use `set()` to get start item(s) - `set(one_list) - set(other_list)`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 3],
    [2, 1],
    [3, 5],
    [3, 6],
    [3, 48],
], columns=('input', 'output'))

print(df)

diff = set(df['input'])-set(df['output'])
print('diff:', diff)

all_starts = list(diff)

for start in all_starts:
    print('start:', start)
```

Result:

```
   input  output
0      1       3
1      2       1
2      3       5
3      3       6
4      3      48

diff: {2}

start: 2
```

---

If you would have only one output for every input then you could use dictionary with `{input: output}` and use `while`-loop to walk dictionary to get path.

```py
d = dict(zip(df['input'], df['output']))

for start in all_starts:
    print('start:', start)

    while start in d:
        end = d[start]
        print(start, '->', end)
        start = end
```

Result:

```
start: 2
2 -> 1
1 -> 3
3 -> 48
```

But if input may have many outputs then it may need recursion to create all possible paths. And it would need more complex code.

---

**EDIT:**

Similar with `DataFrame`

```py
for start in all_starts:
    print('start:', start)

    while start in df['input']:
        all_rows = df[ df['input'] == start ]
        for index, row in all_rows.iterrows():
            print(start, '->', row['output'])
        start = row['output']
```

Result:

```
start: 2

2 -> 1
1 -> 3
3 -> 5
3 -> 6
3 -> 48
```

---

Maybe it would be simpler to use module [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) for work with `graphs`.

**EDIT:**

Code which uses `NetworkX` to create `graph` and search paths.

See also [NetworkX Tutorial](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html).

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

data = [
    [1, 3],
    [2, 1],
    [3, 5],
    [3, 6],
    [3, 48],
]

#for a, b in data:
#    G.add_edge(a, b)

G.add_edges_from(data)

print('G:', G)

for d in nx.descendants(G, 2):
    n = list(G.neighbors(d))
    print('node:', d, '| len(neighbors):', len(n), n)
    #if len(n) == 1:
    #    print('path:', 2, '->', d, '|', nx.shortest_path(G, 2, d))
    print('path:', 2, '->', d, '|', nx.shortest_path(G, 2, d))
    
nx.draw_shell(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Result:

```
G: Graph with 6 nodes and 5 edges
node: 1 | len(neighbors): 2 [3, 2]
path: 2 -> 1 | [2, 1]
node: 3 | len(neighbors): 4 [1, 5, 6, 48]
path: 2 -> 3 | [2, 1, 3]
node: 5 | len(neighbors): 1 [3]
path: 2 -> 5 | [2, 1, 3, 5]
node: 6 | len(neighbors): 1 [3]
path: 2 -> 6 | [2, 1, 3, 6]
node: 48 | len(neighbors): 1 [3]
path: 2 -> 48 | [2, 1, 3, 48]
```

[image]

Comment: I added code which uses `NetworkX` for some calculations.